# How to unzip a Japanese ZIP file, and avoid mojibake/garbled characters

Tags: encoding, zip, japanese, unzip

I received a ZIP file from a Japanese customer.

When I try to unzip it the file and folders names are messed up:

```
$ unzip ~/Downloads/【新入荷ECM】資料.zip
...
 inflating: БyРVУ№Й╫ECMБzОСЧ┐/123_ГЖБ[ГXГPБ[ГX.xlsx
```

What is the problem, and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 22):

The problem is that most ZIPs circulating in Japan have their content [encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) as [Shift JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS), which is not shown correctly by default on Ubuntu.

The solution is to use the `-O shift-jis` option in your command:

```
$ unzip -O shift-jis ~/Downloads/【新入荷ECM】資料.zip
...
 inflating: 【新入荷ECM】資料/123_ユースケース.xlsx
```

This way, the expanded files are perfectly readable in Ubuntu.

Comment: What version of `unzip` are you using?  I am using Info-ZIP v6.0.0 on Cygwin.  The option `-O` is not supported.

Comment: @kevinarpe: The option might have disappeared? In which case you might have to patch unzip using https://gist.github.com/hamano/573753 or use the repository suggested by Sadaharu Wakisaka.

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer for this

```
$ sudo apt install unar
$ unar ~/Downloads/【新入荷ECM】資料.zip
```

**unar** can automatically recognize which encoding is used. It does only extract and not for compressing.

Then use '[convmv](https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/)' to encode text after extract.

```
$ convmv -f shift_jis -t utf8 БyРVУ№Й╫ECMБzОСЧ┐/123_ГЖБ[ГXГPБ[ГX.xlsx --notest
```

Vice versa, if you'd like to create file(s) from utf8 into shift_jis text for windows.

```
$ convmv -f utf8 -t shift_jis <filename> --notest
```

---

Alternative answers, use of Ubuntu Japanese team built automatic encoding '*unzip*' but you have to add [repository](http://www.ubuntulinux.jp/japanese).