# Japanese Fonts do not display properly

Tags: wine, fonts, error-handling, japanese

I'm trying to install a japanese app called UTAU using wine , but whenever I open the installer it doesn't show correctly the japanese character, only a black square instead.
I have the locale ja_JP.utf8 wich is the one I use to open it (`LANG=ja_JP.UTF8 wine ~/Path/to/installer.exe`), I've tried installing it anyways and it does show all the japanese fonts (white squares or gibberish) and the sound doesn't work (not the main problem)

[Japanese only show up in the tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzUcp.png)

Also when I open the installer with wine on the terminal I get this (other blogs say it's nothing)

```
0032:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0032:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0032:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0032:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
```

edit: forgot to mention, my unbuntu is 18.04 and wine 3.0

update: chaged to wine 5.0.1 and now the error when I start the .exe is diferent

```
000f:err:service:process_send_command receiving command result timed out
000f:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"WineBus" failed to start: 1053
0032:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0032:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
```

It was longer, but exacting the original file with `-O shift-jis` option eliminated some of them.

Comment: The software UTAU has been from Windows Vista era, it was/is designed to use Shift_JIS before Unicode got popular. You should extract installer archive with the Japanese supported software e.g. `unar`. https://askubuntu.com/questions/935022/how-to-unzip-a-japanese-zip-file-and-avoid-mojibake-garbled-characters

Comment: Tried both methods, but none of them worked, once I executed the .exe got the same tab as in the image. Also, thank you for this, it will help with the voicebanks in the future.

Comment: Sorry to hear it, I think the best way is to install Virtual XP on your machine. https://w.atwiki.jp/utau2008/ This is the author's blog which has not updated for 7 years. Perhaps look for the alternative software, if you aren't too keen to use UTAU (Visual Basic program is not really professional). [For example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IltWUWoGHhk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved it (kind of), first extract the zip file with the `unar` command, then open the `.exe` using wine `wine Path/to/utau0418e-inst.exe`(without the locale, because utau 4.18 already includes an english patch), the problem seem to be that some latin characters had a Japanese font), the installer still shows the black squares, but once UTAU is installed, there's no broken symbols or squares, the only problem is that it doesn't seem to play sound, but that may be related to another thing.

edit: `utau.exe` can be opened with the locale `ja_JP.utf8` and it will show it in the native language.